# How do I move item from 1 list to another list in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

[image: example_output]

Hi, I'm trying to implement something like this where the user can click on an item and move it from left to right div or list and vice versa (refer to attached image). The list of items needs to be tracked so I'm able to use javascript to do some processing. I saw some websites done this before but not sure what this is called, is there any terminology for this? I'm don't really know what to search on google so I'm a bit stuck currently. Greatly appreciated it if anyone can help with this, thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's a terminology but transfer list is a close one, if you want coding help please provide a reproducible example of what you have tried https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think you have not tried anything yet, but reading about what you have seen so far, I can assume it maybe something like this, multiselect.js - http://loudev.com/ - a popular jQuery plugin that does that thing and is used on  a lot of sites, mostly older ones as this UI is pretty rare in newer and modern sites.

Comment: My approach is using a select list with the maximum height adjusted, then assigning each item with an id so when the middle button is clicked javascript will check which item is selected and rebuild the list but with the selected element at the other box. I think it's a pretty bad implementation so didn't post it haha.

Comment: @ryanhz if it was a good implementation why would you post it on stackoverflow haha. No matter if you think it is bad, share your code so we all can help you make it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `click` event listener to both lists that appends the event target to the other list and deletes the event target.

```js
row1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target != this){
    row2.appendChild(e.target.cloneNode(true));
    e.target.remove()
  }
})

row2.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target != this){
    row1.appendChild(e.target.cloneNode(true));
    e.target.remove()
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul id="row1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="row2">
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing this example. Never knew that you can clone the element and append it to a list directly like this, very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real formal name dedicated for this, but you can find many things resembling what you are looking for with 'multi list', 'multi select list' and 'multi select box'. Angular Material also has a CDK for this called ['droplist'](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists), but they seem to be the only one really using the term.